# FFMPEG & YouTube Live - "Bad Video Settings" - Please use a keyframe frequency of four seconds or less

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

Trying to live stream to YouTube and from my perspective, everything seems to be working fine. However YouTube keeps giving me the following message:

> **Bad Video Settings**
>
> Please use a keyframe frequency of four seconds or less. Currently, keyframes are not being sent often enough, which will cause buffering. The current keyframe frequency is 8.4 seconds. Note that ingestion errors can cause incorrect GOP (group of pictures) sizes.

I've dug around for hours and so far nothing seems to be making any difference. I added **-g 60** and as I didn't fully understand I also tried adding **-g 2** but neither worked. Here is the command I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -safe 0 -i "concat.txt" -c copy -preset veryfast -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 2400k -framerate 30 -g 60 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choices are to ignore the warning or to re-encode.

Because you enabled [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c copy`) your options `-maxrate 2048k -bufsize 4096k -framerate 30 -g 2` are being ignored. You can't use encoding options when stream copying. That's why they are making no difference.

If you want to re-encode remove `-c copy`. The `-g` option should be approximately 2x to 4x your output frame rate, so `-g 60` if your frame rate is 30. If you want to modify frame rate for whatever reason use `-r`, not `-framerate` as that is an input option for some demuxers.

Although users often add it you don't actually need `-strict experimental` because you're not using any experimental features.